# How to "EXPIRE" the "HSET" child key in redis?

Tags: hash, redis

I need to expire all keys in redis hash, which are older than 1 month.

Comment: 2024-03-31: Redis started implementing hash field expiration, and it's planned for an upcoming release. https://github.com/redis/redis/pull/13172

Answer (score 180):

[This is not possible](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/167#issuecomment-2559040), for the sake of [keeping Redis simple](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/242#issuecomment-3512819).

Quoth Antirez, creator of Redis:

> Hi, it is not possible, either use a different top-level key for that
>   specific field, or store along with the filed another field with an
>   expire time, fetch both, and let the application understand if it is
>   still valid or not based on current time.

Comment: this is why redis is such an awesome piece of software. they know where to keep it simple

Comment: @tObi IMHO it happens too often when I find out that some functionality I need in Redis is missing

Comment: @tObi Disagree.  Everyone is just going to implement the same feature in a variety of buggy and less efficient ways.

Comment: @supr can you please explain why [this](https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/167#issuecomment-4442539) works?

Comment: @tObi, I want to implement a simple queue where I INCR a message ID, and then save a message with some ttl. I can't write a Lua script since clustering breaks when dynamically accessing keys in Lua scripts. I can't expire elements of a hash because yay simplicity. So what to do next? Custom sharding + Lua scripts? Use random third-party plugins and hope they are production ready?

Comment: @Liran that works bc it is expiring the entire hash, not individual keys within the hash.

Comment: I created a Redis module in Rust that implements an EXPIREMEMBER command https://github.com/Rush/redis_expiremember_module

It is not as sophisticated as the implementation in KeyDB but was designed for performance.

Answer (score 39):

Redis does not support having `TTL` on hashes other than the top key, which would expire the whole hash. If you are using a sharded cluster, there is another approach you could use. This approach could not be useful in all scenarios and the performance characteristics might differ from the expected ones. Still worth mentioning:

When having a hash, the structure basically looks like:

```
hash_top_key
  - child_key_1 -> some_value
  - child_key_2 -> some_value
  ...
  - child_key_n -> some_value
```

Since we want to add `TTL` to the child keys, we can move them to top keys. The main point is that the key now should be a combination of `hash_top_key` and child key:

```
{hash_top_key}child_key_1 -> some_value
{hash_top_key}child_key_2 -> some_value
...
{hash_top_key}child_key_n -> some_value
```

We are using the `{}` notation on purpose. This allows all those keys to fall in the same `hash slot`. You can read more about it here: https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial

Now if we want to do the same operation of hashes, we could do:

```
HDEL hash_top_key child_key_1 => DEL {hash_top_key}child_key_1

HGET hash_top_key child_key_1 => GET {hash_top_key}child_key_1

HSET hash_top_key child_key_1 some_value => SET {hash_top_key}child_key_1 some_value [some_TTL]

HGETALL hash_top_key => 
  keyslot = CLUSTER KEYSLOT {hash_top_key}
  keys = CLUSTER GETKEYSINSLOT keyslot n
  MGET keys
```

The interesting one here is `HGETALL`. First we get the `hash slot` for all our children keys. Then we get the keys for that particular `hash slot` and finally we retrieve the values. We need to be careful here since there could be more than `n` keys for that `hash slot` and also there could be keys that we are not interested in but they have the same `hash slot`. We could actually write a `Lua` script to do those steps in the server by executing an `EVAL` or `EVALSHA` command. Again, you need to take into consideration the performance of this approach for your particular scenario.

Some more references:

- https://redis.io/commands/cluster-keyslot
- https://redis.io/commands/cluster-getkeysinslot
- https://redis.io/commands/eval

Comment: This approach use more memory than simple keys with expiration time.

Comment: I am fine with expiring the top key and with it all the sub keys ? however can not find how to expire the entire hash with all the keys as well.

Comment: @mjs you can just set the expire on it. `EXPIRE myHashKey 10` expires your hash in 10 seconds. https://redis.io/commands/expire

Comment: @jonlink that looks relevant to setting a key, not a key that belongs to a hash. edit. i see that was what I wanted :p ... i think the problem is perhaps it is not ttl is not updated when you add things to the hash ?

Comment: will this save all the keys to the same shard in a cluster?

Answer (score 23):

This is possible in [KeyDB](https://github.com/JohnSully/KeyDB) which is a Fork of Redis.  Because it's a Fork its fully compatible with Redis and works as a drop in replacement.

Just use the EXPIREMEMBER command.  It works with sets, hashes, and sorted sets.

> EXPIREMEMBER keyname subkey [time]

You can also use TTL and PTTL to see the expiration

> TTL keyname subkey

More documentation is available here: https://docs.keydb.dev/docs/commands/#expiremember

Answer (score 16):

You can use **Sorted Set** in redis to get a TTL container with timestamp as score. 
For example, whenever you insert a event string into the set you can set its score to the event time. 
Thus you can get data of any time window by calling 
`zrangebyscore "your set name" min-time max-time`

Moreover, we can do expire by using `zremrangebyscore "your set name" min-time max-time` to  remove old events.

The only drawback here is you have to do housekeeping from an outsider process to maintain the size of the set.

Answer (score 6):

We had the same problem discussed here.

We have a Redis hash, a key to hash entries (name/value pairs), and we needed to hold individual expiration times on each hash entry.

We implemented this by adding n bytes of prefix data containing encoded expiration information when we write the hash entry values, we also set the key to expire at the time contained in the value being written.

Then, on read, we decode the prefix and check for expiration. This is additional overhead, however, the reads are still O(n) and the entire key will expire when the last hash entry has expired.

Answer (score 5):

The solution I've been come up with:

Lets say I want to expire every 3 minutes:
So im holding the data in 3 fields 0 1 2.
and then i do module% 3 to current time in minutes.

if the module for example == 0
so im using only 1 2 and 0 i delete;
then it change to 1 so im using 2 and 0 and delete 1.

Im not using it and i didnt checked it but im just let you know its possible

Answer (score 4):

There is a [Redisson](https://redisson.org) java framework which implements hash `Map` object with entry TTL support. It uses `hmap` and `zset` Redis objects under the hood. Usage example:

```java
RMapCache<Integer, String> map = redisson.getMapCache('map');
map.put(1, 30, TimeUnit.DAYS); // this entry expires in 30 days
```

This approach is quite useful.

Comment: but how can you create a map? because I do not find any tutorial or a create/set method

Comment: @ZoltánNémeth In Redis map created automatically when first value inserted.

Answer (score 4):

If your use-case is that you're caching values in Redis and are tolerant of stale values but would like to refresh them occasionally so that they don't get too stale, a hacky workaround is to just include a timestamp in the field value and handle expirations in whatever place you're accessing the value.

This allows you to keep using Redis hashes normally without needing to worry about any complications that might arise from the other approaches. The only cost is a bit of extra logic and parsing on the client end. Not a perfect solution, but it's what I typically do as I haven't needed TTL for any other reason and I'm usually needing to do extra parsing on the cached value anyways.

So basically it'll be something like this:

In Redis:

```
hash_name
- field_1: "2021-01-15;123"
- field_2: "2021-01-20;125"
- field_2: "2021-02-01;127"
```

Your (pseudo)code:

```
val = redis.hget(hash_name, field_1)
timestamp = val.substring(0, val.index_of(";"))

if now() > timestamp:
  new_val = get_updated_value()
  new_timestamp = now() + EXPIRY_LENGTH
  redis.hset(hash_name, field_1, new_timestamp + ";" + new_val)
  val = new_val
else:
  val = val.substring(val.index_of(";"))

// proceed to use val
```

The biggest caveat imo is that you don't ever remove fields so the hash can grow quite large. Not sure there's an elegant solution for that - I usually just delete the hash every once in a while if it feels too big. Maybe you could keep track of everything you've stored somewhere and remove them periodically (though at that point, you might as well just be using that mechanism to expire the fields manually...).

Answer (score 3):

Regarding a NodeJS implementation, I have added a custom `expiryTime` field in the object I save in the HASH. Then after a specific period time, I clear the expired HASH entries by using the following code:

```js
client.hgetall(HASH_NAME, function(err, reply) {
    if (reply) {
        Object.keys(reply).forEach(key => {
            if (reply[key] && JSON.parse(reply[key]).expiryTime < (new Date).getTime()) {
                client.hdel(HASH_NAME, key);
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: You can make this more efficient by using `Array.filter` to create an array of `keys` to delete from the hash then pass that to `client.hdel(HASH_NAME, ...keys)` in a single call.

Comment: `const keys = Object.keys(reply).filter(key => reply[key] && JSON.parse(reply[key]).expiryTime < Date.now());
client.hdel(HASH_NAME, ...keys);`

Answer (score 2):

You could store key/values in Redis differently to achieve this, by just adding a prefix or namespace to your keys when you store them e.g. "hset_"

- Get a key/value `GET hset_key` equals to `HGET hset key`
- Add a key/value `SET hset_key value` equals to `HSET hset key`
- Get all keys `KEYS hset_*` equals to `HGETALL hset`
- Get all vals should be done in 2 ops, first get all keys `KEYS hset_*` then get the value for each key
- Add a key/value with **TTL or expire** which is the topic of question:

```
 SET hset_key value
 EXPIRE hset_key
```

**Note**: `KEYS` will lookup up for matching the key in the whole database which may affect on performance especially if you have big database.

Note:

- `KEYS` will lookup up for matching the key in the whole database which may affect on performance especially if you have big database. while `SCAN 0 MATCH hset_*` might be better as long as it doesn't block the server but still performance is an issue in case of big database.
- You may create a new database for storing separately these keys that you want to expire especially if they are small set of keys.

> Thanks to @DanFarrell who highlighted the performance issue related to
>   `KEYS`

Comment: just be aware this is a significant change to performance characteristics

Comment: how! if you talking about time complexities, all these operations have the same time complexity as `hashset` .. get O(1) set O(1) get all O(n)

Comment: "consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care."  https://redis.io/commands/KEYS . HGETALL is `O(n)` for number of things in the set, `KEYS` to number of things in the DB.

Comment: that's true, `scan 0 match namespace:*` might be better as long as it doesn't block the server

Comment: also, separate these keys, if they're small set, to different database. thanks @DanFarrell

Comment: scan is also O(n), this turns HGETALL from O(size_of_hash) to O(size_of_entire_redis_database)

Comment: if you have a few 100K keys, then you will find SCAN, while not blocking other calls for long, will see your REDIS CPU hit 100%

Answer (score 0):

You can. Here is an example.

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> hset key f1 1
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> hset key f2 2
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> hvals key
1) "1"
2) "1"
3) "2"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> expire key 10
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> hvals key
1) "1"
2) "1"
3) "2"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> hvals key
1) "1"
2) "1"
3) "2"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> hvals key
```

Use [EXPIRE](http://redis.io/commands/expire) or [EXPIREAT](http://redis.io/commands/expireat) command.

If you want to expire specific keys in the hash older then 1 month. This is not possible.
Redis expire command is for all keys in the hash.
If you set daily hash key, you can set a keys time to live.

```
hset key-20140325 f1 1
expire key-20140325 100
hset key-20140325 f1 2
```

Comment: I don't think he wants to expire *all* keys in the hash, rather *all keys in the hash which are older than 1 month*, so only some of them.  Which AFAIK is not possible.

Comment: IMHO the question let us assume this. So Jonathan gets +1 from me, cos he helped me out! Thanx!

Comment: how do you expire "f1" and "f2" ?

Comment: This does not answer the question or helps at all. The need is to expire the elements in the hash, not the hash itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Redis Keyspace Notifications by using `psubscribe` and `"__keyevent@<DB-INDEX>__:expired"`.

With that, each time that a key will expire, you will get a message published on your redis connection.

Regarding your question basically you create a temporary "normal" key using `set` with an expiration time in s/ms. It should match the name of the key that you wish to delete in your set.

As your temporary key will be published to your redis connection holding the `"__keyevent@0__:expired"` when it expired, you can easily delete your key from your original set as the message will have the name of the key.

A simple example in practice on that page : https://medium.com/@micah1powell/using-redis-keyspace-notifications-for-a-reminder-service-with-node-c05047befec3

doc : https://redis.io/topics/notifications ( look for the flag xE)

Answer (score 0):

```js
  static async setCount(ip: string, count: number) {
    const val = await redisClient.hSet(ip, 'ipHashField', count)
    await redisClient.expire(ip, this.expireTime)
  }
```

Try expire your key.

Answer (score 0):

I created a Redis module in Rust that implements an EXPIREMEMBER command https://github.com/Rush/redis_expiremember_module

It is not as sophisticated as the implementation in KeyDB but was designed for performance.