# Redis pattern: how would you cache free / occupied ressource with expiration?

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

Here is the problem I was working on this week, and I am kind of hitting a wall here.

Let's say I have 100 resources available to do some quick task.

What I want to do is for the client, as fast a possible:

1. fetch the first available ressource
2. mark it as occupied
3. use it
4. mark it as free.
   For this kind of thing, I think the use of a sorted set is the best.

But because my client is not very safe and can sometimes fail in the middle of the code it runs I really want to set expiration time when I mark a resource as occupied so resources are can't in the occupied state forever.

It sounds like a very common problem and I'm sure there is a lot of literature out there on how to fix it with Redis but I could not find any.

I found many patterns and example for "Maintaining a global leaderboard" kind of problem, but none of those examples dealt with key expiration.

I currently have a solution like this:

```
for ressource in ressources:
    if GET <ressource> == 0:
        SET <ressource> 1, EX=10
        use_ressource(<ressource>)
        SET <ressource> 0, EX=10
    else:
        continue
```

Thing is, as soon as I have lots of resources used, this can take lots of operations to find the first free resource, and although Redis is really fast, this snippet does not scale well.

Comment: how are the resources stored? is it stored in redis? can we pick a data structure to store it in redis or is it a predefined restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

- Maintain a set of free resources
- Maintain a set of used resources
- Set up a [keyspace listener](https://redis.io/topics/notifications) on the `expired` event notification

When a resource is needed, randomly select one with [`SRANDMEMBER`](https://redis.io/commands/srandmember) and move it to the in-use resources set with [`SMOVE`](https://redis.io/commands/smove). In this same transaction, set up a simple expire key with a good prefix, the name/type of the resource, and required TTL with [`SETEX`](https://redis.io/commands/setex).

Set up a redis keyspace notification consumer (still new, but check out their newest tech [Redis Gears](https://redislabs.com/redis-enterprise/technology/gears/) for a super simplified version of this!) that listens to the `expired` events for your assigned prefix. When one of these events occurs, run the same `SMOVE` logic above but just move the resource back into the free resources set.

Regarding the actual resources themselves, when they finish, have them self-expire their tracking keys and the notification consumer can handle the state refreshing :)

This should give you the flexibility you need!

---

Similar question here, and some answers may be of use: [How to "EXPIRE" the "HSET" child key in redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545321/how-to-expire-the-hset-child-key-in-redis?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you very much ! Learned a lot with that answer and it actually look exactly like what I need.