# Reset value for key in redis

Tags: redis

I am storing some values in `redis` like for `key: 1` the value will be

```
{"counter":1,"counter1":2}
```

Now I need to reset value of `counter` while the `counter1` should be remaining same.

To increase counter I am use the command `SETEX mykey 60 redis` .

But it will also reset the value of `counter1`. So is there any way I can reset one value for a single key.

Let me know if I need to add some more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `string` you may use `hash`, then it will be easy. you can `increment` by some other value, `delete` counter etc etc. Each key in your json will be `hash field`.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hset mykey counter 1 counter1 2
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall mykey
1) "counter"
2) "1"
3) "counter1"
4) "2"
127.0.0.1:6379> hset mykey counter 25
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall mykey
1) "counter"
2) "25"
3) "counter1"
4) "2"
127.0.0.1:6379> HINCRBY mykey counter 15
(integer) 40
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall mykey
1) "counter"
2) "40"
3) "counter1"
4) "2"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Comment: So if I use  SETEX mykey 10  then both counter will be reset right? If I am right then how can I avoid that ? I want to reset only counter value in every 1 minute not the counter1 value.

Comment: @Soham you won't use setex you will use hset - the solution i provided shows how to reset a single field while keeping other the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But I need to reset the value after say 1 minute.So can I give some expiry time in seconds using hset.

Comment: @Soham it is not possible with hash (you can't partially expire a field) - you can completely expire hash. There are some misused terms i think in your question. But i offered this solution as "reset" means "reset"ting/setting it to zero the value not "expire"ing completely.

Comment: @Soham you may check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545321/how-to-expire-the-hset-child-key-in-redis

Comment: Sorry if my question isn't clear at all. Your answer is fine according to my question so I am accepting your answer.